# Laravel only returns first result from db using with

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

For my API I need to return a role with its corresponding permissions.

The database look like:
[image]

Model role:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany( Permission::class );
}
```

Model permissions:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany( Role::class );
}
```

When I use the following function from RoleController:

```
/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Role  $role
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit( Role $role )
{
    return response()->json( $role->with('permissions')->first(), 200 );
}
```

I only get the first result from roles even tough I send a different `$role`. Meaning if I send role `2` or `3` I get the results from role `1`.

However I also checked the `$role` which does return the right role (`2`)

The permissions from role `1` do return tough so the main question is why do I only get the first result from the database?

Comment: Maybe you should remove `->first()` from `return response()->json( $role->with('permissions')->first(), 200 );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `$first` obtains the first record in the database. If you already have the role object, you should change the query to the following:

```
$role->load('permissions')
```

This will [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) the permissions.

Comment: I did know that `$first` returns the first record of the database that's why I didn't use `get()`. But didn't know about `load()` which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you're doing:

```
$role->with('permission')->first()
```

you're actually running another database query on the `Role` model which is giving you the first role, no matter which role you actually pass through. If you want to get the first permission, you need to do something like this:

```
$role->permissions->first();
```

That will load the `permissions` relation and grab the first item in the collection. As others have suggested, if you need to eager load a relation when you already have an object, you can use the `load` method:

```
$role->load('permissions');
$firstPermission = $role->permissions->first();
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you use `first()` method, which basically return the first result.
Use `get()` instead to return a collection.

Comment: I would advice against this solution, because he already has an object loaded, where `get()` would also retrieve more than one role. This is not the behaviour he wants.

Comment: Right. I didn't notice `with()` would do a new SELECT query on the roles table.